# Should an app remember its last state after re-opening from background by push notification?

Tags: usability, mobile, navigation, app, push-notification

Imagine this scenario:

There's a mobile app. The user navigates between different app pages. The last page the user visits is the **Edit profile** form. Then the user goes to the iPhone home screen, which sends the app to the background. While the app is running in the background, the user gets a push notification from the app. Pressing the notification bar re-opens the app on the **Notifications** screen.

Here's the question:

Should the app remember its last state - the **Edit profile** form - and provide a possibility to go back from **Notifications** to **Edit profile**?

Answer (score 1):

If the user is leaving the app, typically when they return to the app, they will land on the screen they were last on.

However, if the user has left the app and has tapped on an app push notification from their home/lock screen, the expectation is they will be brought back to the app to the page/activity related to the notification if not the same page they left.

Comment: This is exactly what I am describing in my scenario. The user gets back to the app after pressing the push notification. The app opens in the related to the push-notification page. BUT, the last activity - Edit profile - is gone now. Should there be a way to go back to the Edit profile? Or this can be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

This is my analysis:

1. If returning to the app from the notification alert goes directly to the notification page, there should an alert in the app indicating the user has a pending task
2. If returning to the app from the notification alert goes to the page the
   user was working on, there should be an alert indicating the
   user has a new notification

From these two options, the second in my opinion is more logical.

- It's much more common in many apps to get or see a notification alert than a pending task alert.
- A pending task can be sporadic, while notifications are usually more frequent

Google Analytics example:

[image]

Comment: I expect the app to open a related to the push-notification item